# How to prevent newtxmath from turning any delimiter bold?

Tags: bold, newtxmath, stmaryrd

I use `newtxmath` to use nonitalic bold Greek letters. However, it makes `\llbracket\rrbracket` bold. For instance,

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{newtxmath} % for Greek variants (bold, nonitalic, etc...)

\begin{document}
$\llbracket a+b\rrbracket$
or
$[ a+b\rrbracket]$$
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

instead

[image]

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just load `stmaryrd` after `newtxmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxmath} % for Greek variants (bold, nonitalic, etc...)
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

$\llbracket a+b\rrbracket$

$[a+b]$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, however, the brackets don't match. Here's the output without `stmaryrd`.

[image]

Comment: That is great! But is it possible to newtxmath from turning any delimiter bold?

Comment: @RubemPacelli They aren't bold. They are that way in order to mix with Times, which has quite heavy vertical strokes.

Comment: What do you mean by "the brackets don't match"?

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas The shapes are distinctly different.

Comment: @egreg I honestly don't see the difference but it is true that I have poor vision.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Look at the inner corners: they're rounded in NewTX, but “straight” in the StMaryRd bracket.

Comment: Now I get it: I mistakenly understood that you were talking about a discrepancy between the right *and left* brackets.